# Audio onclick in canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick

I am building a musical application in which when an area is pressed, a sound will be produced. However I am unable to link the sound file to my shape on the canvas.

I am using the `moveTo` & `lineTo` methods to create my shape and would want to implement a sound file to the area. How do I go about doing this? Should I be using an element or a function?

Currently, this is what I have so far:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="850" height="250" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

    <script>
    $(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var C = (function () {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(20, 20);
      context.lineTo(60, 20);
      context.moveTo(20, 20);
      context.lineTo(20, 230);
      context.moveTo(60, 20);
      context.lineTo(60, 160);
      context.moveTo(60, 160);
      context.lineTo(75, 160);
      context.moveTo(75, 160);
      context.lineTo(75, 230);
      context.moveTo(75, 230);
      context.lineTo(20, 230);
      context.stroke();
      return(this);
      }

      var sound = new Audio("C.wav");
    sound.preload = 'auto';
    sound.load();

    function playSound(volume) {
    var click=sound.cloneNode();
    click.volume=volume;
    click.play();
}
```

Comment: One way to do it is to create a mouse click event listener for the canvas and the check if the mouse coordinates are within the shape you have created. Use `ctx.isPointInPath()` to determine if the mouse is over the shape when clicked. If so then play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it.. Include a button to trigger the playSound() method. In the playSound() method you can also call your C() method to draw the shape.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="playSound(1)">Play sound</button>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="850" height="250" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var C = (function() {
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(20, 20);
      context.lineTo(60, 20);
      context.moveTo(20, 20);
      context.lineTo(20, 230);
      context.moveTo(60, 20);
      context.lineTo(60, 160);
      context.moveTo(60, 160);
      context.lineTo(75, 160);
      context.moveTo(75, 160);
      context.lineTo(75, 230);
      context.moveTo(75, 230);
      context.lineTo(20, 230);
      context.stroke();
      return (this);
    });

    var sound = new Audio("C.wav");
    sound.preload = 'auto';
    sound.load();

    function playSound(volume) {
      C();
      var click = sound.cloneNode();
      click.volume = volume;
      click.play();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```